# Missing parameter definition when deploying adf with bicep

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-bicep

I am deploying an adf with bicep similar to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-move-files template from microsoft. It worked nicely when I ran the pipeline by editing in the UI. I then exported the arm template from the datafactory and have converted it into a bicep template with the same exact parameters. However I get this error message when deploying:

Status Message: Missing parameter definition for SourceStore_Location,SourceStore_Directory

Should I not be able to reference the parameters like this? Have anyone done something similar?

```
resource dataFactoryPipeline 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines@2018-06-01' = {
  parent: dataFactory
  name: pipelineName
  properties: {
       parameters: {
      SourceStoreLocation : {
        type: 'String'
        defaultValue: 'xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx'
      }
      DestinationStoreLocation : {
        type: 'String'
        defaultValue: 'xxxx\\xxxx'
      }
      SourceStoreDirectory : {
        type: 'String'
        defaultValue: 'xxxx'
      }
      DestinationStoreDirectory : {
        type: 'String'
        defaultValue: 'xxxx'
      }
    }
    activities: [
      {
        name : 'GetFileList'
        type: 'GetMetadata'
        typeProperties: {
          dataset: {
            referenceName: sourceDataSetName
            type: 'DatasetReference'
            parameters: {
              FolderPath: {
                value : '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Location'
                type: 'Expression'
              }
              Directory: {
                value: '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Directory'
                type: 'Expression'
              }
            }
          }
          fieldList: ['childItems']
          storeSettings: {
            type: 'FileServerReadSettings'
            recursive: true
          }
          formatSettings: {
            type: 'DelimitedTextReadSettings'
          }
        }

      }
      {
        name : 'FilterFiles'
        type: 'Filter'
        dependsOn: [
          {
            activity: 'GetFileList'
            dependencyConditions: [
              'Succeeded'
            ]
          }
        ]
        typeProperties: {
         
         
        items:{
          value: '@activity(\'GetFileList\').output.childItems'
          type: 'Expression'
        }
        condition: {
          value: '@equals(item().type, \'File\')'
          type: 'Expression'
        }
        }

      }
      {
        name : 'ForEachFile'
        type: 'ForEach'
        dependsOn: [
          {
            activity: 'FilterFiles'
            dependencyConditions: [
              'Succeeded'
            ]
          }
        ]
        typeProperties: {
          items: { 
          value : '@activity(\'FilterFiles\').output.value'
          type : 'Expression'
        }
        activities: [
          {
            name : 'CopyFile'
            type: 'Copy'
            typeProperties: {
              source: {
                type: 'DelimitedTextSource' 
                storeSettings: {
                  type: 'FileServerReadSettings'
                  recursive: true 
                }
                formatSettings: {
                  type: 'DelimitedTextReadSettings'
                }
              }
              sink: {
                type: 'DelimitedTextSink'
                storeSettings: {
                  type: 'AzureFileStorageWriteSettings'
                }
                formatSettings: {
                  type: 'DelimitedTextWriteSettings'
                  quoteAllText: true 
                  fileExtension: '.txt'
                }

              }
            }
            inputs: [
              {
                 referenceName: sourceDataSetFileName
                 type: 'DatasetReference'
                 parameters: {
                  FolderPath: {
                    value : '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Location'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                  Directory: {
                    value: '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Directory'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                  FileName: {
                    value: '@item().name'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                 }     
              }
            ]
            outputs: [
              {
                referenceName: sinkDataSetName
                type: 'DatasetReference'
                parameters: {
                  FolderPath: {
                    value : '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Location'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                  Directory: {
                    value: '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Directory'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                  FileName: {
                    value: '@item().name'
                    type: 'Expression'
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        { 
          name : 'DeleteFiles'
          type: 'Delete'
          dependsOn: [
            {
              activity: 'CopyFile'
              dependencyConditions: [
                'Succeeded'
              ]
            }
          ]
          typeProperties: {
            dataset: {
              referenceName: sourceDataSetFileName
              type: 'DatasetReference'
              parameters: {
                FolderPath: {
                  value : '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Location'
                  type: 'Expression'
                }
                Directory: {
                  value: '@pipeline().parameters.SourceStore_Directory'
                  type: 'Expression'
                }
                FileName: {
                  value: '@item().name'
                  type: 'Expression'
                }
              
              }
              
            }
            storeSettings: {
              type: 'FileServerReadSettings'
              recursive: true 
            }
          }

        }
        ]
        
         
        }

      }
      
    ]
 
  }
  dependsOn: [
    sinkDataSet
    sourceDataSet
    sourceDataSetFile
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strangely it seems like it may have fixed itself? I hardcoded the parameters in the different activities and then added the expressions one by one, deploying the template to weed out where it stopped. In the end I added them all and then suddenly it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Status Message: Missing parameter definition for SourceStore_Location,SourceStore_Directory:

The above error shows that the deployment requires the parameters `SourceStore_Location` and `SourceStore_Directory`. Check whether the parameters are correctly passed in your bicep script/template.

If still the issue persists, you can pass those parameters with the
[`az deployment group create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-create-examples)command as follows:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group <resourcegroup> --template-file <filename.bicep> --parameters SourceStore_Location='' SourceStore_Directory=''
```

*I tried the deployment in the above manner, and it worked as expected.*

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.DataFactory/2018-06-01/factories/pipelines?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) for the bicep template of data factory pipelines.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As you can see in my code I have input the parameters at the start of the pipeline, is this not enough? I unfortunately cant use the az deployment  command as this is all deployed another way via github actions.

Comment: Sometimes you need to pass the input parameters with the az deployment command. Then only it works. @ProgH

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not doing this approach, unless you plan on not using the UI of the Data Factory editor. Unfortunately similar to Logic Apps, at this time only ARM templates is supported via the export out of the developer UI. This means this conversion, to be consistent, would have to occur every time. Also for the record your flow would go form ARM->Bicep->ARM at a technically level since Bicep will recreate the ARM templates for deployment.

Additionally the export process will combine the ARM templates defined in the datasets, linked services, and templates to create a consolidated ARM template via the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities). The parameters will also need to be tracked as things change.

Comment: We are actually not using the UI to make the changes. Everything gets deployed through IAC. The export was just used as a helping tool after testing in the UI. Everything else gets deployed just fine

Comment: I'm not commenting that it wouldn't technically work. Just from an overall development perspective it seems to introduce redundant steps. An alterative approach would be to disable publish functionality in the portal and let your CI/CD execute entirely in the codebase..